# jQuery on() not firing on appended a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a feeling this is an embarrassingly simple mistake I'm making but I just can't see it at the moment.

I have a table which I'm dynamically appending rows to - the the final column of each row contains a link that, when clicked, should remove that row. At the moment, the rows are being added fine but I can't figure out why the event's attached to the remove buttons aren't firing. I've removed the removal code to test with console.log() but I'm seeing nothing in the console.

I know on() should work with appended HTML, what am I missing?

http://jsfiddle.net/52Pbk/

HTML:

```
 <div id="people">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Second Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    <a href="#" id="add">Add</a>
```

JS:

```
var html = '<tr>';
            html += '<td><input type="text" /></td>';
            html += '<td><input type="text" /></td>';
            html += '<td><input type="text" /></td>';
            html += '<td><a href="#" class="remove_btn">x</a></td>';
        html += '</tr>';

$('.remove_btn').on('click', function() {
       console.log('REMOVE BUTTON CLICKED');            
    //$(this).parent().parent().remove();
                return false;
            });

$('#add').on('click', function() {
    $('#people').append(html);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are binding the `click` event handler to all current DOM elements. You need to use this syntax of `.on()` for event delegation for future dynamically created elements.

```
$("#people").on("click", ".remove_btn", function(e) {
  console.log('REMOVE BUTTON CLICKED');         
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

You need to use `.on()` in a parent element that is not modified. I used `#people` in this case. But, you can also narrow it using a closer parent element.

Comment: Thanks a lot man - that was exactly it! only recently transferred to on() so getting used to it. Cheers! (will accept the answer in 5 minutes when I'm allowed to)

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you apply event on elems which are not available in the dom. So you have to delegate the event to its closest existing parent:

```
$('table#people').on('click', '.remove_btn',function() {
```

Answer (score -2):

This is just an order issue. You need to append the HTML before you call the code to register the onclick event.

```
$('#add').on('click', function() {
    $('#people').append(html);

    $('.remove_btn').on('click', function() {
           console.log('REMOVE BUTTON CLICKED');            
               //$(this).parent().parent().remove();
                        return false;
                });


    return false;
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not what OP is asking for

Comment: @cIph3r, that's even worse. That's rebinding the event handler